# Why were the "L" names directly on the other side of the "D" names?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, Scott Lang goes to a Snap memorial in LA, where he sees several stones with lists of names on them of people who died. However, he goes from one side of a stone, with last names beginning with "L", to the other side, which has names beginning with "D". The next stone he moves onto has the same thing. So why is "D" right across from "L"?

[image: Picture of the "D" side]
[image: Picture of the "L" side]
[image: Alternate picture of the "L" side]

Comment: Got a pic? Do you mean same side of the same "stone"? If so that makes sense: left to right in rows so either side wouldn't line up under that presumption.

Comment: I don't think that's the only alphabet problem in that scene, actually.  I think the way the scene is directed is more worried about moving Scott around in a compelling and dramatic way than with the logic of the set dressing of the memorial.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I don't have a screencap right now, but yeah, opposite sides of the same "headstone"

Comment: Who says they have to be in alphabetical order? The Vietnam Wall memorial is not.

Comment: But all the names on the one side are L

Comment: And all the names on the other side are D

Comment: Maybe the names are in concentric rings

Comment: If we can get an image that would really help, and potentially there is a logical explanation that the image would help draw out.

Comment: @Jontia I've uploaded images

Comment: FWIW, there's a list of names at https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Wall_of_the_Vanished including a mention about how most of them are production staff and family with Roberta DaCosta (aka Sunspot from *The New Mutants*) being an exception.

Comment: BTW, those names are **not** in alphabetical order.

Comment: Dextrorotatory and Laevorotatory? :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would not find it odd about a very large war memorial that one side shows names starting with a D and the one opposite it shows names starting with an L.

There are many World War memorials here in Hungary.  Most of them display, carved into stone, an alphabetized list of names of the local soldiers who died for the country.  It is not uncommon that the list continues on three or even four sides of the base of a statue, or on an obelisk.  I would like to present here two memorials that have a situation similar to what you're asking about.

The first is [**the Porta Heroum in Szeged**](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Porta_Heroum).  This is a very large  memorial for World War I on a building that arches over a street.  The names are listed on the sides of the pillars that hold up the building and form three arches where the passengers and vehicle traffic of the street pass.  The lists are on the sides of the pillars facing inside, large protected from the weather.  There are names on multiple pillars on both sides of the street.  Besides the list of names and the usual statues of helmeted soldiers, this monument features colorful murals painted on the curved inner walls of the arch.

Here's a photo showing the overall layout of the monument, and a photo that shows some of the names that start with S or Sz.  (There's a tablet that only has names starting with K, and only half of those names even, but I don't have a good photo of that one.)  The latter is to demonstrate that on an even larger monument, it would be possible to have a side that shows only names starting with D.  Both photos are my own, taken on 2012-08-14.

[image: (overall layout of Porta Heroum, Szeged)]

[image: (tablet with list of names Sé–Szi in Porta Heroum, Szeged)]

The other is [**the World War I memorial in Budafok**](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:World_War_I_memorial_in_Budafok) (from 1926).  This is a life-size bronze statue of a helmeted soldier holding a fallen comrade in his arm, sitting on a rectangular base.   The stone covering the sides of the base is engraved.  The list of the fallen heroes is on three sides: the right side has the names from A to H, the left side from H to S, and the back from S to Zs plus a few names probably added after most of the list was engraved.

Here are photos of the right and left side showing that two names that start with D happen to be directly opposite to some names starting with L.  Photos from 2012, credit to Bence Damokos, thumbnails here are linked to the source.

[image: (Budafok World War memorial, two names starting with D highlighted.)]
[image: (Budafok World War memorial, two names starting with L highlighted.)]

Comment: Good real life example here

Answer (score 7):

If all the entries go across the front side of a bunch of stones and then across the back sides of the same stones, then there's no reason D shouldn't be opposite L.

Comment: This is probably the correct answer (modulo other issues as alluded to by tbrookside in the comments) but without any images to verify this against it's really basically a guess.

Comment: If we really wanted to be pedantic about it, someone would try to estimate how many names there should be based on the range of names we see and available demographics of the area.   Obviously if that makes any sense versus the number of stones then it's just dumb luck.

Comment: "If we really wanted to be pedantic..."  _If_?!  It's like you don't know us at all.